# Unable to dissolve faces

Tags: geometry

I want to dissolve faces as shown [in this video](https://youtu.be/O1ofHLNzAwc?t=38).
In this video (please watch it at 0.25), the author turns some faces into "holes".

I try to do the same, but for me, it doesn't have any effect:

[image]

Why does it not work as in the video?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: why do you want to dissolve one single face? you can only dissolve 2 faces (so they merge together).

Comment: [Gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) work well to explain when images are not alot help also...

Comment: @Sanbaldo I did try that, it didn't work. I have tried to follow a tutorial: https://youtu.be/O1ofHLNzAwc?t=38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutor used an operator in the delete menu *delete only faces*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what I want to do. In my post, I have inserted a link to the video that I want to replicate. In this video, the selected faces are turned into holes, while in your answer, you remove the faces.

Comment: Argh, I was stupid! In the video he selected "Delete faces", not "Dissolve faces". I will delete my post.

Comment: I didn't realize you had commented :) was editing

Comment: The site warned me about deleting my post, so rather leave it open, ok? Thank you!

Comment: Someone will learn from it, that's the nice thing about this site :)